# PHP cURL not working for localhost with remote server relation

Tags: php, curl, file-upload, localhost, remote-server

I'm currently working on copying a file from localhost to a remote server using PHP cURL.

I have two separate files, one for the localhost which sends the file, and another for the remote server to receive the file and save it to the server. The codes are as follows :

send.php

```
<?PHP
  $web_page_to_send = "http://admin123.unaux.com/receive.php";
  $file_name_with_full_path = "test.jpg";
  $post_request = array
  (
    "sender" => "tmp", 
    "file" => curl_file_create($file_name_with_full_path)
  );
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $web_page_to_send);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_request);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo "<br>Result: ".$result;
?>
```

receive.php

```
<?PHP
  if(isset($_POST['sender']))
  {
    echo "got it !";
    $file_name = "tmp/".$_POST['sender']."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file_name);
    echo "Successful Attempt! <br><br>Filename: ".$file_name;
    echo '<br><br> <img src="'.$file_name.'" width="300px"></img>';
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'Unauthorized Access!';
  }
?>
```

The codes are working fine on localhost, but after placing the receive.php to the remote server, the file is no more sent and displayed. "http://admin123.unaux.com/receive.php" is where the file is on the remote server. I'm using [profreehost](https://profreehost.com/) free server as the remote server.

Remote server folder structure : [Remote Server File and Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBC15.jpg)

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I would add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` to see if there are any issues from the send.php

Comment: The output is : Result: 1

Comment: The send.php file is not able to contact the receive.php file on the remote server...

Comment: problem solved, the code works fine with a paid server...

Answer (score 0):

Please get all received data in the receive.php file as below:

```
$post_data = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

after this, try to print $post_data. If you will get null value then response is not hitting at your file.
Try to send above data with below code:

```
$web_page_to_send = "http://admin123.unaux.com/receive.php";
$file_name_with_full_path = "test.jpg"; // Please write here full file path in the system
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $web_page_to_send,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 20,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('sender' => 'tmp','file'=>new CURLFILE($file_name_with_full_path)),
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                            "Content-Type: image/jpg"
                           ),
  CURLOPT_UPLOAD=>true,
 ));
 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 $http_response = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: can you please send the complete codes, for both the files please...

Comment: Already send you the code for send.php and in the receive.php first of all check that data is coming to that file or not. $post_data = trim(file_get_contents("php://input")); print_r($post_data); If data is printed then your issue solved. then you will do whatever you want to with these data.

Comment: on running the send.php with the code that you provided is returning me an empty page.

Comment: Are you providing the full path of your file(test.jpg)?

Comment: $file_name_with_full_path = "C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.jpg";

Comment: Please add CURLOPT_UPLOAD=>true, in the above curl request and try.

Comment: still a blank page, and no file upload...

Comment: problem solved, the code works fine with a paid server...